# Wordpress ajax возвращает пустоту

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Я делаю динамическую загрузку станица тобишь кнопку "Показать еще". Все работает, вот только я не могу удалить эту кнопку. Когда последние элементы загружены, запрос возвращает пустоту, ни `undefind`, ни `null` и даже не пустую строку `''`, в консоле просто пустое сообщение. Как отследить это я не имею ни малейшего понятия.

Запрос

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('.house-post').last().after(data);
            button.data('page', nextPage);
            console.log(data);
        } else {
            button.remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Запрос во всех случаях возвращает статус код 200 и что интересно, пустой запрос имеет `Content-Length: 2`.

Comment: Желательно показать код, что именно и на каком моменте вы выводите в консоль, ну и свойственно то, что должно приходить в ответ (так же, необходимо чекнуть статус ответа в (Браузер->Инструменты разработчика->Network->Ищите свой запрос и смотрите код ответа)).

Comment: Если Content-Length: 2 - может возвращаются пробелы?

Comment: @Quazimorda, можно было бы это как-то отследить. Пробовал if ```(data == "   ") { console.log("true); }```, не реагирует.

Comment: @Malyuga так раз длина - 2, то и пробелов может быть два. На стороне сервера, где запрос что-то возвращает в php используйте функцию trim перед проверкой на то, пустая строка вернулась или нет.

Comment: @Quazimorda, да ```trim()``` сработал для меня. Спасибо! Можете добавить это как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Content-Length: 2 - может возвращаются пробелы? Вероятно 2 пробела подряд. На стороне сервера, где запрос что-то возвращает в php используйте функцию trim перед проверкой на то, пустая строка вернулась или нет.